# Display different selection menus based on response to previous menu in Shiny

Tags: r, shiny

I'm trying to dynamically display different selection menus in shiny based on a user response to a previous menu.  For example if the user selects a 'campaign_id' of Launch Sequence, they should get a drop down menu with the appropriate options.  However, if they select Sale Event they should get a numeric text entry for the discount %.  I've created all the appropriate selection menus, but now I need to figure out how to dynamically display them.  I tried using ifelse logic based on the response to the previous question, but it always displays the menu associated with all false responses.

I suspect that when the logic is evaluating the previous response that response isn't formatted correctly, or has some html in there so the logic always evaluates to false.  I've included a simplified example of what I'm experiencing.  Any help is greatly appreciated.

```
library(shiny)
library(tidyverse)

# data referenced 1
cid <- tibble(
  name = c(
    'Free Content',
    'Launch Sequence',
    'Mega Sale',
    'Sale Email',
    'Sale Reminder',
    'VSL Push'
  ),
  abbr = c('FC',
           'LS',
           'MS',
           'SE',
           'SR',
           'VP')
)

# data referenced 2
csid <- tibble(
  name = c(
    'Free Content',
    'Launch Sequence',
    'Launch Sequence',
    'Launch Sequence',
    'Launch Sequence',
    'Launch Sequence',
    'Mega Sale',
    'Sale Email',
    'Sale Reminder',
    'VSL Push'
  ),
  subname = c(
    'topic text entry',
    'Launch Sequence1',
    'Launch Sequence2',
    'Launch Sequence3',
    'Launch Sequence4',
    'Launch Sequence5',
    'NA',
    'discount numeric entry',
    'NA',
    'url'
  ),
  abbr = c(
    'NA1',
    'LS1',
    'LS2',
    'LS3',
    'LS4',
    'LS5',
    'NA2',
    'NA3',
    'NA4',
    'NA5'
  )
)


ui <- fluidPage(
                titlePanel("Example Selection"),     
                
                sidebarLayout(
                  sidebarPanel(
                    selectInput(
                      inputId = 'campaign_id',
                      label = 'Campaign ID',
                      choices = c(cid$name)
                    ),
                    
                    uiOutput(ifelse(
                      # which selection menu to display based on campaign_id
                      'cid' == 'Launch Sequence',
                      'ls',
                      ifelse(
                        'cid' == 'Free Content',
                        'fc',
                        ifelse(
                          'cid' == 'Sale Email',
                          'se',
                          ifelse('cid' == 'VSL Push',
                                 'vp',
                                 'mssr')
                        )
                      )
                    )),
                    
                    
                    textInput(
                      inputId = 'date',
                      label = 'Launch Date',
                      placeholder = paste0('use date format "', Sys.Date(), '"')
                    )
                    
                    
                  ),
                  
                  ############### Main panel for displaying outputs ----
                  mainPanel(
                            textOutput(outputId = "campaign_name"))
                ))

############## server functions --------------------------------------
server <- function(input, output) {
  # build campaign sub-id list based on campaign selected ----
  cidselected <- reactive({
    input$campaign_id
  })
  
  output$cid <- renderText({
    cidselected()
  })
  
  output$ls = renderUI({
    selectInput(
      inputId = 'campaign_subid',
      label = 'Campaign Sub-ID',
      choices = c(
        'Launch Sequence1',
        'Launch Sequence2',
        'Launch Sequence3',
        'Launch Sequence4',
        'Launch Sequence5'
      )
    )
  })
  
  output$fc = renderUI({
    textInput(inputId = 'campaign_subid',
              label = 'Campaign Sub-ID',
              placeholder = '1-3 word description of main topic')
  })
  
  output$vp =  renderUI({
    textInput(inputId = 'campaign_subid',
              label = 'Campaign Sub-ID',
              placeholder = 'enter VSL url here')
  })
  
  output$mssr = renderUI({
    selectInput(inputId = 'campaign_subid',
                label = 'Campaign Sub-ID',
                choices = c('N/A'))
  })
  
  output$se = renderUI({
    numericInput(
      inputId = 'campaign_subid',
      label = 'Campaign Sub-ID (enter as whole number 40% = 40)',
      value = 0,
      min = 0,
      max = 100
    )
  })
  
  output$campaign_name <-
    renderText({
      # display combined name with abbreviations
      cid = cid$abbr[cid$name == input$campaign_id]
      csid = input$campaign_subid
      date = gsub('-', '', input$date, fixed = T)
      paste(cid,
            csid,
            date,
            sep = '-')
      
    })
  
  
}

shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It sounds like you're looking for [conditional panels](https://shiny.rstudio.com/reference/shiny/1.6.0/conditionalPanel.html). There are more complex methods if you have more input selections/combinations (you can create a uiOutput which is dynamically created in server.R, for one), but this is the simple and straightforward way to do what you want.